# Git clone existing repository after given tag

Tags: git

Because of disk space, and network bandwidth, I would like to clone a linux repository starting from a given tag (let's say v3.13).
I have managed to clone only that tag using `--depth` and `-b`.

```
$ git clone -b v3.13 --depth=1 https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git
[ cut ]
$ git log
commit d8ec26d7f8287f5788a494f56e8814210f0e64be
Author: Linus Torvalds <torvalds@linux-foundation.org>
Date:   Sun Jan 19 18:40:07 2014 -0800

   Linux 3.13
```

Now let's say I want to keep track of work done in linux, I would like to retrive commits from 3.13 to (for instance) 3.14.

```
$ git pull origin v3.14 --update-shallow
[ asks me to merge ]
$ git log
commit 9a50c0fe200b079731a61aea1760b8adc44150ec
Merge: d8ec26d 455c6fd
Author: me <me@plop.org>
Date:   Tue Mar 29 17:31:54 2016 +0200

    Merge tag 'v3.14' of https://github.com/torvalds/linux into v3.13

    Linux 3.14

commit 455c6fdbd219161bd09b1165f11699d6d73de11c
Author: Linus Torvalds <torvalds@linux-foundation.org>
Date:   Sun Mar 30 20:40:15 2014 -0700

    Linux 3.14
[...]
# G goes to the end
commit 1da177e4c3f41524e886b7f1b8a0c1fc7321cac2
Author: Linus Torvalds <torvalds@ppc970.osdl.org>
Date:   Sat Apr 16 15:20:36 2005 -0700

    Linux-2.6.12-rc2
    [...]
```

Obviously something went wrong, because I had to merge commits (but I didn't change any files), and more importantly, I got the whole history from the repository; which is precisely what I wanted to avoid.

How can I update my repository without bringing the whole history preceding the initial commit provided on clone?

Comment: Just FYI, there is some work going on the in the [nd/shallow-deepen](https://github.com/gitster/git/commits/nd/shallow-deepen) branch which might make it easier in the future to cover this use-case.

Comment: Thank you! I must admit I have some issues understanding git philosophy. "Larger is better". I'll give a look to that branch then.